# Hostapd no internet on server

Tags: linux, networking, debian, hotspot, hostapd

I have setup local "hotspot" on my machine running Debian Jessie.

I followed some instructions after which neither of tutorials worked for me.
In the end I discovered I had a whitespace (I think) in my `interfaces` and `hostapd.conf` file which was preventing it from loading. So in the end I managed to get it working. But since I used different tutorials I'm not sure if some of the software I installed can be causing it.

My problem now is that when I boot my computer I can connect with my Android and access internet, but my computer itself cannot access it. only if I modify `interfaces` and comment out all the bridge information then it works (but then as you can guess, my android is down)

So here are some of my configurations:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# wireless wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

# eth0 connected to the ISP router
allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Setup bridge
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
    address 192.168.1.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    ## isp router ip, 192.168.1.2 also runs DHCPD ##
    gateway 192.168.1.2
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.2
```

**/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**

```
### Wireless network name ###
interface=wlan0
### Set your bridge name ###
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

### (IN == INDIA, UK == United Kingdom, US == United Stats and so on ) ###
#country_code=IN

ssid=PrettyFlyWiFy

hw_mode=g

channel=6

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mysuperstrenthypasswordgoesherebutaintgonnawrite it here

## Key management algorithms ##
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
## Set cipher suites (encryption algorithms) ##
## TKIP = Temporal Key Integrity Protocol
## CCMP = AES in Counter mode with CBC-MAC
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
## Shared Key Authentication ##
auth_algs=1
## Accept all MAC address ###
macaddr_acl=0
```

and this is my **ifconfig eth0** when the internet is up on the server itself

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.9.146  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.9.255
        inet6 fe80::beae:c5ff:feb7:90e0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:ae:c5:b7:90:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1315564  bytes 1425606866 (1.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 682171  bytes 66122362 (63.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my **/etc/resolv.conf** in the same scenario

```
domain ciu.edu.tr
search ciu.edu.tr
nameserver 10.0.0.46
nameserver 10.0.0.9
```

[also it maybe useful to note that the last tutorial I used was this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/)

Comment: In the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, you should replace this line, `bridge_ports wlan0 eth0`, with **bridge_ports eth0**.  First, putting the wifi interface into the bridge should be done by hostapd, read for instance `/usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz`; second, once hostapd is started, the wifi interface will be put into monitor mode, hence its name will become **mon0* or some such thing.

Comment: Done as you suggested, removed wlan0 from the line. nothing really changed, even wlan0 has the same name in ifconfig

Comment: I did not say that was the **only** probelm your config has: if I had thought so, I would have posted the above as an answer. there is more to dig...